# Distinct on specific column using JPA Specification

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to write the following query using JPA Specification.
select distinct name from hcp where area = 'Dhaka';

```
select distinct name from hcp where area = 'Dhaka';
```

The hcp entity looks as following

```java
@Entity
public class HCP implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String area;
}
```

The table would look like this

[image]

I tried to convert the above query using jpa-specification as following. It's selecting 'name' field and I've set distinct as true

```java
List<HCP> result = hcpRepository.findAll(new Specification<HCP>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<HCP> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                query.select(root.get("name")).distinct(true);
                return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("area"), "Dhaka");
            }
        });
```

But it's not working. It's only applying district on the field that has @Id annotation. I want to apply distinct on `area` field.

Generated Hibernate Query looks like this:

```
select
        distinct hcp0_.id as id1_0_,
        hcp0_.area as area2_0_,
        hcp0_.name as name3_0_ 
    from
        hcp hcp0_ 
    where
        hcp0_.area=?
```

How can I get generated query like the following?

```
select
        distinct hcp0_.name as name3_0_
        from
            hcp hcp0_
        where
            hcp0_.area= 'Dhaka'
```

The desired result will list distinct names based on area.
How can I apply distinct on a specific field using JPA Specification?

Desired query and output:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYSbP.png]

Comment: But you want HCP as a result. So you cannot use distinct like this. What should be the result of your query?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Hello, Thank you for pointing it out. I've updated the question with desired output and more information. Hope it'll clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Specifications because you want to return a List of Strings.

So you could use JPQL

```
@Query("select distinct h.name from Hcp h where area = 'Dhaka'")
List<String> findDistinctName();
```

Comment: Thank you. If not a list of string then is it possible to get count using Specifications? like for ```select count(distinct name) from hcp where area = 'Dhaka';``` or for this also I need to use JPQL.

Comment: You shouldn't use specification for that. This would be "select count(h) from hcp h where area = 'Dhaka' group by h.name"